# Spring boot logging how to set logging.file.max-size unlimited

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-logback

I am working with **spring boot** application where I am using **logback** for **LOGGING** purpose and I want to store my log on log file with **unlimited size** but default size of **logging.file.max-size** property is **10MB** can anyone help me that what value I need to set on **logging.file.max-size** to achieve unlimited file size for log file?

Comment: I think you should not go for unlimited size. Perhaps it is appropriate to have an unlimited amount of logfiles, but: what do you want to do with logs that are several months old ?

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to set an unlimited size as such, but there is a workaround
You can set a huge limit for the max size, like this:

```
logging.file.max-size: 100000GB
```

Set this in application.yml or application-test.yml
If your machine has more than 100,000 GB of disk space, you can use a higher number ;].

**Background:**
Spring boot loads this default config file: org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml
That file includes: org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml
Which uses SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy

Answer (score 6):

Log files rotate when they reach `10 MB` and, as with console output, `ERROR-level, WARN-level, and INFO-level` messages are logged by default. Size limits can be changed using the `logging.file.max-size` property. Previously rotated files are archived indefinitely unless the logging.file.max-history property has been set.

More customization you can do for logging, please refer [Spring Boot Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

Comment: logging.file.max-size is deprecated, use logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size instead

Comment: @AybekKokanbekov Sa, they deprecated it. Using logging.logback...mean it works only for logback. If one day, i change the library to log4j2, then it not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

add below in your logback.xml

```
<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
```